# Concept of parallel transport and its physical intuition

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I am currently reading Foster and Nightingale and when it comes to the concept of parallel transport, the authors don't go very deep in explaining it except just stating that if a vector is subject to parallel transport along a parameterized curve, there is no change in its length or direction and hence its derivative with respect to the parameter is equal to zero.
Later, there is an example of a vector being parallelly transported on a latitude of a sphere and its final direction is different from the initial direction at the same point! Then how can we say that it was parallelly transported since it wasn't so in the conventional sense?
I am unable to get the concept of parallel transport.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport is a bit technical, but you may find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics) helpful, although it's pretty technical too. I understand you want something more intuitive, but it's hard to avoid the mathematics with this stuff. ;) The key idea is that at each local infinitesimal step of parallel transport the direction (& magnitude) of the vector is unchanged, but when we get back to the starting point there is a discrepancy due to the curvature.

Answer (score 4):

> Then how can we say that it was parallelly transported since it wasn't so in the conventional sense?

This is what curvature is, basically.

Recall a simpler example, if $A_\mu$ is a (co-)vector field, you can integrate it against a curve: $$ I[\gamma]=\int_\gamma A_\mu\mathrm dx^\mu=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}A_\mu\frac{\mathrm d\gamma^\mu}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt, $$ let's say between two points $x_0=\gamma(t_0)$ and $x_1=\gamma(t_1)$. Does this integral depend on the curve or only one the end-points?

As it turns out it does depend on the curve, unless there is a scalar function $\phi$ such that $A_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi$, in which case the integral depends only on the end-points.

But the *local* integrability condition for the equation $A_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi$ is that $\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu=0$, so if we define $C_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$, then the tensor field $C_{\mu\nu}$ is a local measure of the path-dependence of that integral.

---

For connections, the situation is very similar, we need to make the substitutions

- $A_\mu\Rightarrow\text{connection}$
- $\text{integral}\Rightarrow\text{parallel transport}$
- $C_{\mu\nu}\Rightarrow\text{curvature}$

If a connection $\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\nu}$ is given, and $v^\mu$ is a tangent vector at the point $x_0$, you can always define the parallel transport of $v^\mu$ along a curve $\gamma^\mu(t)$ ($\gamma(t_0)=x_0,\ \gamma(t_1)=x_1$) by integrating the ordinary differential equation $$ \frac{\mathrm d V^\mu}{\mathrm dt}=-\Gamma^\mu_{\kappa\lambda}\frac{\mathrm d\gamma^\kappa}{\mathrm dt}V^\lambda,\quad V^\mu(t_0)=v^\mu, $$ which admits unique solutions given the initial data $V^\mu(t_0)=v^\mu$ by the usual theorems on ODEs. In fact, the solution of this differential equation can be expressed in closed form as the path-ordered exponential of an integral (see "parallel propagator" in Carrol's General Relativity book).

However one can ask the same question we did for the integral of a vector field - does the value of this depend on the shape of the curve or only on the end-points. As it turns out, it depends only on the end-points if $\Gamma$ has the form $$ \Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\nu}= \frac{\partial^2 u^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial x^\kappa}{\partial u^\alpha} $$ for some functions $u^\alpha$ (that are invertible with respect to the coordinates $x^\mu$), and the *local* integrability condition for that is $$ R^\kappa_{\ \lambda\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu\Gamma^\kappa_{\nu\lambda}-\partial_\nu\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\lambda}+\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\rho}\Gamma^\rho_{\nu\lambda}-\Gamma^\kappa_{\nu\rho}\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\lambda}=0, $$ where $R^\kappa_{\ \lambda\mu\nu}$ is the curvature tensor.

Ergo, one has curvature if there cannot be given a path-independent meaning of parallel transport that avoids the paradoxical results the OP has mentioned. Parallel transport is still very much consistent when done along a given curve, but there is no *absolute* sense of parallelism in a space with nonvanishing curvature$^\ast$.

---

$\ast:$ Even in a space with vanishing curvature there can be *topological* obstructions to absolute parallelism, but only for non-homotopic paths. See the Aharonov-Bohm effect for a physical example.

Answer (score 2):

Given a generic curved manifold, at each point you can draw a tangent plane. This is the vector space associated with that point in which the vectors live. Now even two nearby points in this manifold has independent tangent spaces(the tangent space of one is independent of the other). So how can you talk about differentiation of vectors? Well you introduce the idea of a "connection". This literally connects one tangent plane to the other. It basically gives you an algorithm to transform the basis of one vector space to the other one. Then parallel transport just means that given a connection(there can be infinitely many different "connections") what vector can you write in the second tangent plane that imitates the first one in first tangent plane.

Now the question is: suppose I want to go from one point to another. Does my sense of "parallel" depend on the path I take? Absolutely yes! If it isn't so, then you can draw arbitrary set of curves covering the whole manifold and then parallel transport the vector along all those curves to get a parallel vector field on the whole manifold. That cannot be true in general(in fact, it's only true for manifolds with zero curvature!). This path dependence is the reason for the problem you're stating. Uplifting the idea of "parallel" to curved manifolds taught us that it's in general dependent on the path we take.